# Perl script to print the last modified subdirectory in a directory

Tags: perl

I am writing a Perl script to print the last modified subdirectory in a directory.

For example, the directory structure is as follows

```
amr/lex/
amr/kik/
amr/rtr/
amr/rtr4/
apr/rtr6tyh/
amr/rtr6yhu/
amr/d5tyh/
amr/d5kuk/
..
..
..
```

All these directories in `amr` like `lex`, `kik`, `rtr`, `rtr4`, `rtr6tyh`, `rtr6yhu`, `d5yh` etc. have subdirectories

I have to print the last modified subdirectory in them

For example

`amr/lex` has 2 directories `s1.0` and `s2.0`. I have to print the last modified-by date and time.

I have this so far

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;

my $path = '/main/amr';
my $directory;
my @sub_dir;
my $var;


opendir ($directory, $path);

@sub_dir = readdir($directory);

print "@sub_dir";

foreach $var (@sub_dir)
 {
  opendir (my $temp, $var);
  my @arr = readdir ($temp); 
  print "@arr\n";
 }
```

---

I have the following script
But it is acting erratic, it print the most recent modified for some but not for others

```
use strict;

my $path = '***<specify your own path >***';
my $directory;
my @sub_dir;
my $var;
my $var1;

my $now = time();
my $curr = 0;  # most recent modified time
my $latestDir; # most recent sub dir

my $temp;

opendir ($directory, $path);

@sub_dir = readdir($directory);

foreach $var (@sub_dir) # dirA, dirB
{

#print "Test123 ". $path ."/". $var . "\n"; (for debug)

if($var ne "." && $var ne "..") {
      opendir ($temp, $path ."/". $var);
      my @arr = readdir ($temp);



   foreach $var1 (@arr) { # subdir1
     if($var1 ne "." && $var1 ne "..") {
       my @stats = stat($var1); #call method stat on each subdir stat[9] - latest modified time

       #print $var1 . "\n";
         if($now-$stats[9] < $now-$curr || $curr == 0) {
             $curr = $stats[9];
             $latestDir = $var1;
     }
    }
 } # end foreach
print $latestDir . "                   " .  $var  . "\n";
}
}# end foreach
```

Any idea whats wrong here...
Any help is much appreciated

Comment: You seem to be missing [`use File::Find;`](http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Find.html) and you aren't using the code therein.

Comment: Thank for the reply, 
I am trying to read the directory, store it into an array and go from there....
not sure if that is the right approach..

Comment: @Miller: I think you should say more than *"added 46 characters in body"* when you edit someone else's post

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: The OP says they want to *"print the last modified sub directory in a directory"*. Using `File::Find` to do that would be awkward and unnecessary

Comment: Please give examples for the output that you want

Comment: @Borodin s/added \d+ characters in body/formatting/;  Or to be more specific in this case, used Borodin's Cntl-K trick.  Yer right though, even for quick updates, should aim to write an intentional description to teach the OP's.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work using [`File::Find`](http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Find.html):

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Find;

$ARGV[0] = "." unless scalar @ARGV;
my $new_name = $ARGV[0];
my @info = stat $new_name;
my $new_time = $info[9];

sub wanted
{
    my(@info) = lstat($_);
    my($mod_time) = $info[9];
    if (-d _ && $mod_time > $new_time)
    {
        $new_name = $File::Find::name;
        $new_time = $mod_time;
    }
    return;
}

find(\&wanted, @ARGV);
print "$new_time: $new_name\n";
```

It's Perl so TMTOWTDI — There's More Than One Way To Do It.  There might also be ways to optimize the code, or make it more succinct.

It gave plausible answers such as:

```
1395633608: .
```

then when I created a file in (pre-existing) sub-directory SHA-256, it listed:

```
1395633641: ./SHA-256
```

then when I checked in a change with `git`, it gave:

```
1395633722: ./.git
```

---

Using a different interpretation of the question as suggested by [Borodin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/622310/borodin) in his [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22599897/perl-script-to-print-the-last-modified-subdirectory-in-a-directory/22600902#comment34411061_22600902), you can modify the script above to use a hash indexed by directory name, with the entries being hash refs where the referenced hash has keys `sub_dir` (the name of the immediate sub-directory) and `mod_time` (the modification time of the identified sub-directory).

I'm using Perl 5.18.2 on Mac OS X 10.9.2 Mavericks, but you should be OK unless your Perl is older than about 5.12.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Find;

$ARGV[0] = "." unless scalar @ARGV;

# dir_mod_times is indexed by directory and contains hash refs
# with keys sub_dir and mod_time.
my %dir_mod_times = ();

sub wanted
{
    my(@info) = lstat($_);
    my($mod_time) = $info[9];
    if (-d _)
    {
        my $ref = { sub_dir => $_, mod_time => $mod_time };
        $dir_mod_times{$File::Find::dir} //= $ref;
        $dir_mod_times{$File::Find::dir}   = $ref
            if ($mod_time > $dir_mod_times{$File::Find::dir}->{mod_time});
    }
    return;
}

find(\&wanted, @ARGV);

foreach my $dir (sort keys %dir_mod_times)
{
    printf "%d: %s/%s\n", $dir_mod_times{$dir}->{mod_time},
           $dir, $dir_mod_times{$dir}->{sub_dir};
}
```

Sample output:

```
1395635479: ./.
1395633721: ./.git/objects
1384144591: ./.git/logs/refs
1395598709: ./.git/logs/refs/heads
1395598709: ./.git/logs/refs/heads/so
1395633721: ./.git/objects/02
1395633722: ./.git/refs/heads
1395598709: ./.git/refs/heads/so
1384651972: ./SHA-256/so-20020953-sha256.dSYM
1384651972: ./SHA-256/so-20020953-sha256.dSYM/Contents
1384651972: ./SHA-256/so-20020953-sha256.dSYM/Contents/Resources
1384651972: ./SHA-256/so-20020953-sha256.dSYM/Contents/Resources/DWARF
1395629945: ./time.dSYM/Contents
1395629397: ./time.dSYM/Contents/Resources
1395629945: ./time.dSYM/Contents/Resources/DWARF
```

And then when I removed `SHA-256/junk` (an empty file):

```
1395635569: ./SHA-256
1395633721: ./.git/objects
1384144591: ./.git/logs/refs
1395598709: ./.git/logs/refs/heads
1395598709: ./.git/logs/refs/heads/so
1395633721: ./.git/objects/02
1395633722: ./.git/refs/heads
1395598709: ./.git/refs/heads/so
1384651972: ./SHA-256/so-20020953-sha256.dSYM
1384651972: ./SHA-256/so-20020953-sha256.dSYM/Contents
1384651972: ./SHA-256/so-20020953-sha256.dSYM/Contents/Resources
1384651972: ./SHA-256/so-20020953-sha256.dSYM/Contents/Resources/DWARF
1395629945: ./time.dSYM/Contents
1395629397: ./time.dSYM/Contents/Resources
1395629945: ./time.dSYM/Contents/Resources/DWARF
```

Comment: You may have understood the OP better than me, but your solution addresses only the title of the question. It reads to me like they want the youngest subdirectory of each child directory of `/main/amr`. +1 anyway

Comment: @Borodin: I see now how you are interpreting the question differently from me.  I think it could be done with a hash and other appropriate changes.

Answer (score 0):

Your program opens the directory `/main/amr` and then tries to open everything in that directory as another directory.

I'm hoping that what you want is just a list of directories in `/main/amr`, in which case this short program will help. It uses [`File::Spec::Functions`](https://metacpan.org/module/File%3a%3aSpec%3a%3aFunctions) to build the full file path for each member of the directory, which is clearer and more portable than using `join`

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use File::Spec::Functions 'catfile';

my $path = '/main/amr';

opendir my ($dh), $path;

while (my $node = readdir $dh) {
  my $fullpath = catfile($path, $node);
  print "$fullpath\n" if -d $fullpath;
}
```

Comment: This lists the directories; I see no testing of modification times.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: There is none. I wanted to establish that my deviation from the OP's code was valid before enhancing it

Answer (score 0):

This is a wee bit tricky because it depends upon your definition of the *modification time* of the directory. The directory (like all files) have an *mtime* associated with them. This is the last time a directory was modified. For example, I added a file to a directory, the directory was modified. If I modify a file in the directory, it doesn't update the *modification time* of the directory because the directory itself was not changed.

So, are you strictly talking about the modification time of the directory, or are you talking about the time anything in that directory (or maybe even a subdirectory of that directory) was modified? For example, I modified a file in that directory, should I take that as the last time the directory was modified even if the directory wasn't changed?

Taking the easy way out, we'll simply talk about the modification time of the directory as reported by the `ls -l` command.

First, in your script, you need to either check the status of your `opendir` command to see if you've successfully opened the directory, or use `use autodie;` to automatically *die* if you cannot open the directory. I'll use `use autodie;` since it's the recommended way of doing things now.

You can also use the `-M` *test* to return the number of days (in fractional part) of when the directory was last modified. Much easier than using `stat` to get the `mtime`.

I also recommend to declare variables with `my` when you actually need them instead of at the very beginning of your program as if you're writing in Cobol or Pascal. Variables with `my` fall in and out of scope and that can be a useful attribute of the variable. For example, if I define a variable in a loop, the variable will cease to exist once I leave the loop.

Here's what I did:

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl
#
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature qw(say);
use autodie;

my $directory = ".";

opendir ( my $dir_fh, $directory);

my $youngest_date;
my $youngest_subdir;
while ( my $subdir = readdir $dir_fh ) {
    next unless -d $subdir;
    next if $subdir eq "." or $subdir eq "..";

    # If this is the first subdirectory, set it as the youngest and go to the next

    if ( not defined $youngest_subdir ) {
        $youngest_date = -M $subdir;
        $youngest_subdir = $subdir;
        next;
    }

    # See if this subdirectory is younger than the youngest found so far

    if ( $youngest_date > -M $subdir ) {
        $youngest_date = -M $subdir;
        $youngest_subdir = $subdir;
    }
}

if ( $youngest_subdir ) {
    say "Youngest Subdirectory is $youngest_subdir.";
}
else {
    say "No subdirectories found.";
```

Note that I define `$youngest_date` and `$youngest_subdir` outside of my loop. That way, they'll exist in each interaction of the loop and once the loop finishes. However, `$subdir` itself will go out of existence in each iteration of the loop (where it gets created again), and disappears completely once my loop is done.

The first thing I do is to skip any entry that's not a directory ( `next unless -d $subdir;` ) and to skip the `.` and `..` directories. You might want to skip any directory that starts with a period.

Once I have a directory, I get it's age with the `-M` command and check it against `$youngest_date` which is the youngest modification date I have found. Notice too that I have to handle the initial condition when I get the first directory (`if ( not defined $youngest_subdir ) {`).

I also have to verify that there was a subdirectory found before I can print out my results.

Comment: Your code looks promising,
how do i run your script?